# What are some free extensions for delivery date in checkout?

Tags: checkout, extensions, magento2.2.6, delivery-date

We are in Magento2.2.X. We would like to implement the delivery date field into the checkout. When I have googled, I have found the below free extension but it hasn't worked for me.

https://marketplace.magento.com/rage-delivery-date.html

I have tried to find some other free extensions but no success. Could anyone please tell me what are the free extensions for a delivery date?

Comment: Check https://sohel.dev/2016/06/18/magento-2-order-delivery-date-extension/

Comment: What is the issue you're facing in this extension? https://marketplace.magento.com/rage-delivery-date.html this is working for me

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran After installed this extension, I can access the configuration page successfully via admin panel but in the frontend, the template is not loading.

Answer (score 1):

Below extensions may help you:

Free:

https://github.com/saphaljha/magento2-module-delivery-date

Paid:

https://magecomp.com/magento-2-delivery-date.html
https://amasty.com/delivery-date-for-magento-2.html

You can create your own custom module:

https://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/